# Image import issue with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So this program is supposed to just put a sprite on screen. But the image is not importing right. I made sure the image has no background, but in the program, part of the background turns black while the other half stays transparent. Its really weird.

heres my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import pygame
from livewires import games

#Creating screen window
games.init(screen_width = 700, screen_height = 650, fps = 50)

#creating background image for the screen
screen_background = games.load_image('resized_stars background.png', transparent = False)
games.screen.background = screen_background

#Creating a sprite
spaceship_image = games.load_image('8-bit_Spaceship.png')
spaceship = games.Sprite(image = spaceship_image, x=350, y=235)
games.screen.add(spaceship)

#main loop at the end of the program just as in tkinter
games.screen.mainloop()
```

Why will it not show up on screen properly?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use, and it works just fine:

First, create the screen:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen width, screen height))
```

Then:

```
spaceship = pygame.image.load("direct it to the image")
```

An example of directing it to the image would be "C:/PythonFolder/spaceship.png"
I see you just put the name of the file.

Then, when you're ready to blit (append) it to the screen, use

```
screen.blit(spaceship, (x location, y location))
```

Then update it:

```
pygame.display.update()
```

or:

```
pygame.display.flip()
```